# Specify the table containing the records you want to delete

Tags: sql

`TableOne` and `TableTwo` are joined so that they include rows where the joined fields (called `TableOne.ID` and `TableTwo.ID`) from both tables are equal.

I need to delete from TableOne and TableTwo the rows where TableTwo.FieldName is a certain value.

I tried this:

```
DELETE FROM TableOne 
INNER JOIN TableTwo ON TableOne.ID = TableTwo.ID
WHERE TableTwo.FieldName = 'example';
```

but I get the error:

```
Specify the table containing the records you want to delete
```

I have checked tons of times that tables' names and fields' names are correct. So I think there is something wrong with the syntax.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name mmm hoping that this answers your question, I am using SQL through VBA with the code `CurrentDb.Execute <SQL_text>`

Comment: But against which DBMS? (Your delete statement is invalid standard SQL)

Comment: @user7867367 - Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the table as:

```
DELETE t1, t2
    FROM TableOne as t1 INNER JOIN
         TableTwo as t2
         ON t1.ID = t2.ID
    WHERE t2.FieldName = 'example';
```

Although MySQL lets you delete rows from multiple tables at the same time, cascading constraints are usually a more robust solution.

Comment: well, thank you. but the problem persists :( I used your code with the addition of `AS` because I am using SQL through a VBA for an Access Form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
DELETE TableOne.* FROM TableOne 
INNER JOIN TableTwo ON TableOne.ID = TableTwo.ID
WHERE TableTwo.FieldName = 'example';
```